# If a Muslim man marries a Christian woman, what are the conditions for the wedding ceremony?

Tags: nikah, christianity

I know that Muslim men can marry Christian or Jewish women, but how must the ceremony take place?

Does it have the be in a mosque and performed by an Imam? Naturally, the woman would prefer it to take place in a Church. Can it be performed in a neutral place, such as a secular venue performed by a non-religious person so it would be valid in the law, but what about within Islam?

Comment: when you say Christian or Jew do you mean their beliefs are monotheistic? Nowadays most Christians fall under the category of Mushrikoon as they associate partners with Allah, such as Trinity, etc

Comment: @fluuufffy Many would disagree, since the time of the prophet many of the Christians did believed in the Trinity, it wasn't a new thing. Maybe you should start a new question about this to continue the discussion.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim But the problem is that they have altered what GOD made lawful and what HE prohibited to match their own desires. Also on side note, marriage to people of the book was only allowed to 'chaste'/'pious' women. Though it was allowed yet it was disliked, as was mentioned that better for you are the believing slaves than them. They were considered better than the non-believer women.

Answer (score 5):

In Islam, there are a [5 requirements](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/1766) to a valid marriage contract:

- Both parties (Husband and Wife) are clearly named. For example, a person can't say I marry you my Daughter when he has more than 1 daughter.
- Both parties are OK with the marriage.
- The wali is present (Father, Brother, Closet relative, Caliphate, Sheikh) in that order.
- At least 2 witnesses.
- They can marry Islamically (linage wise, one being an unbeliever (not the people of the book)).

You should make it easy on yourself. If she wants to serve Beer/Pork it shouldn't be an issue since their religion allows it, just make sure there is a Halal option and Muslims who attend know about it. Also make sure that her family does pay for the non Islamic food so you won't get sins for it.

The venue also matters, personally I wouldn't recommend Masjid and go with a wedding hall instead, since she is not a Muslim.

You can go to the local Masjid, perform the Islamic Aqid there in an office setting with the wife/her wali (Masjid is usually occupied so its easy to get witnesses) and then re-do it again in the wedding hall, if needed, which is what most people I know do who marry non Muslims.

Comment: See [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39155/17702) regarding "Both parties are OK with the marriage." - in at least two madhahib, there are constellations where the girl's/woman's consent is not required.

Answer (score 2):

It could be at any place so long as being in that place is not haram from a Muslim e.g. a place where wine/alcohol is served, it's not ritually clean.

What's *required* is that the marriage/nikah be properly and carefully pronounced and mehr decided<sup>*</sup>. The nikah should be pronounced by a Muslim (be it Imam or the groom) irrespective of religiousness.

This is on the bases of Islamic law (the only one which matters) irrespective of the law of the country in which the marriage takes place.

The wedding ceremony should be take place within the precepts of Islam.

<sub>*</sub>

- <sub>AFAIK witness is required in case of Sunni Islam</sub>
- <sub>duration of marriage decided in case of Shia Islam, since permanent marriage it not permitted with the people of the Book which includes Christians. Only temporary is. And in case of women neither is.</sub>