# Is the practice of "marrying the Qur'an" allowed?

Tags: quran, nikah, women, muslim-practices

In F. Viqar and F. Saeed, *Women's bodies, men's decisions: Women's control over sexual and reproductive health in Pakistan*, Sexualities, Culture and Society in Muslim Contexts, 2014, Dossier 32-33 ([link](http://www.wluml.org/resource/dossier-32-33-sexualities-culture-and-society-muslim-contexts)), we have the following footnote on page 140:

> In areas of Pakistan, some women are "married to the Quran", a practice which guarantees they remain celibate.  This action is usually undertaken to protect family inheritence, when it is at risk of being shared with the husband of a daughter or a sister who has not found a suitor from within the family.  The roots of this practice are found in the feudal culture where land is equated with family honour.

It is described as occurring in the [Sindh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindh) region of Pakistan.  It also mentions women being married to a glass of water, and a particular case, Allah Wasai from the [Cholistan desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholistan_Desert), being married to a pigeon.

I'm not sure how seriously I take being married to a glass of water or a pigeon.  But...

**Question**: Is the practice of "marrying the Qur'an" allowed?

I'm guessing the answer is a resounding no.  But if it goes against Islam, and scholars became aware of its practice, I'd expect there to be fatwas declaring in haram, which is what I seek in this question.

Comment: _Haq Bakshish_ (the practice you are referring to) is only practiced in some areas in Pakistan to the best of my knowledge. I doubt that there will be fatwas (I could not find any) by prominent scholars on a topic that may not have come to their attention. This practice is not endorsed by Islam as per [Qur'an](https://quran.com/57/27/) and [hadith](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/67/11). Marriage in Islam is between a male and female to establish a family based on [tranquility and affection](https://quran.com/30/2/).

Comment: This is weird, the quran gives a woman the right not to get married (24:60).

Comment: @Medi Though Islam gives women the right to say no, practically the girl/woman is forced by her relatives/guardians to marry against her will. We all know God forbids such acts and He will do justice to the wronged sisters on Judgement Day. On our part, we need to make others aware of their right & ask them to reach the legal authorities where possible.

Comment: @Ahmed I agree, but again forced actions are considered as invalid by shari'a.

Comment: See [this post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39155/walis-right-to-marry-off-a-virgin-without-her-consent-in-different-madhahib) regarding the claim that no one can be married off against their will in Islam; tldr: it's not true.

Comment: @G.Bach you seem to look for answers that fit your opinion. Yeah they can be married against their will, based on statements of scholars, but once they seek a court by the opinion of the same scholars they can nullify the marriage too.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I look for answers that I can substantiate; if there's a significant voice in fiqh with a given opinion, then that should be acknowledged. If you've got any references that scholars who subscribe to the works cited in that thread also say "and once they're married, the wife can easily get out of the marriage by unilateral annulment", feel free to make a question about the issue, answer it yourself, and link to it on that thread; would be interesting context.Those texts read to me like marrying off a virgin against her will to a suitable man is a valid marriage according to them.

Answer (score 1):

A marriage involves two persons to get legally bonded with each other as husband and wife. Quran is not a person, its simply the sum of revelations obtained by prophet Muhammad pbuh from Gabriel as per his claim. Therefore, Quran cannot be used as a substitute of a person.

Quran is suppose to give you instructions on how to be a muslim. Quran acknowledges marriage as a medium for a couple male and female to have sexual intercourse with each other to ease their sexual lusts and possibly produce offspring. If a person marries Quran then he/she will never be able to ease his sexual desires and thus the phrase 'Marry a Quran' is incorrect by the definition of marriage in Quran.

So, these people in Pakistan are doing something which has no place in Quran or Islam.